# scale up kafka nodes in the cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

we have 7 node clusters in QA and 7 node clusters in Production.
7 node clusters are:

1. one - Ambari
2. 3 - kafka
3. 3 - zookeeper and NiFi

Currently, kafka QA sending data to NiFi QA and Kafka Prod sending data to NiFi Prod.
we have requirement to eliminate NiFi QA and send the data from Kafka QA to Prod NiFi since we are combining QA NiFi flow and Prod NiFi flow in a Production NiFi server.

as per the intruction given in the URL, https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#troubleshooting_kerberos
we changed:

1. conf/zookeeper.properties in QA zookeeper
2. Connect String property in server properties file in kafka QA
3. /etc/hosts file which already 7 QA nodes mentioned, we added 3 nodes of Prod NiFi in Kafka QA

After following the above steps, when we create kafka topic in QA:
`sudo /usr/hdf/3.1.2.0-7/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper ProdIPaddress_of_zookeeper1:2181, ProdIPaddress_of_zookeeper2:2181, ProdIPaddress_of_zookeeper3:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic connectiontest`

i am getting same error:

```
[2021-03-04 13:19:48,249] ERROR An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - LOOKING_UP_SERVER)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2021-03-04 13:19:48,250] ERROR SASL authentication with Zookeeper Quorum member failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedAjavax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - LOOKING_UP_SERVER)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) 
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkAuthFailedException: Authentication failure
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.waitForKeeperState(ZkClient.java:947)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.waitUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:924)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1231)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:157)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:131)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:115)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:97)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:56)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Basically, i want clusters to be:

1. 1 Prod Ambari
2. 3 Kafka QA  which will send data to QA NiFi flow in Prod NiFi server
3. 3 Kafka Prod which will send data to Prod NiFi flow in Prod NiFi server
4. 3 Prod NiFi and Zookeeper

What am i missing. Please help on this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - you have a Kafka kerberos issue, so you followed a NiFi troubleshooting guide? You say you are creating a QA Kafka topic, but you're pointing at Prod ZooKeeper in the create topic command? Why? Sharing a ZK between Prod and QA Kafka is a terrible idea (it sounds like NiFi + ZK are co-located, which is also a bad idea).

Comment: When i checked about the error, i found that the same error was mentioned in NiFi troubleshooting guide. Basically i want to send data from kafka QA to Prod NiFi and Kafka prod to Prod NiFi.  I am not sure that whether i should separate zookeeper and keep only one for this scenario.

Comment: Sharing a ZK is a bad idea, your current error is a Kafka issue, nothing to do with NiFi - and is likely because of the shared ZK - I assume QA and PROD are different realms and domains? This will complicate the setup for no benefit - you should keep a QA ZK, even if its co-located on Kafka nodes (if performance doesnt matter in QA). With a working QA Kafka, NiFi can talk to as many different Kafkas as you want, it doesn't care - but it will need valid krb creds & config (i.e. add QA realm to NiFi host krb realms).

Comment: i understood. Yes QA and Prod are different realms and domains. How about keeping Kafka QA with Zookeeper QA which send data to NiFi Prod and Kafka Prod with Zookeeper Prod which also send data to NiFi Prod? I guess by correct config of krb NiFi prod can talk to Kafka QA and Kafka Prod. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes - first resolve the Kafka issue & get a working QA Kafka with a QA ZK. Then you can have 1 Prod NiFi which can consume from both QA & Prod Kafka. You will probably need to add the QA realm to the Prod Nifi hosts krb5.conf as an additional realm. Then Nifi can have a Prod kafka flow, using Prod krb creds, and a QA kafka flow using QA creds.

Comment: I am able to send data from Kafka QA to NiFi QA and Kafka Prod to NiFi Prod. My requirement now is to send data from Kafka QA to NiFi Prod